# Long writing time, short reading time from hdf5 file to numpy stack using Dask

Tags: arrays, numpy, store, dask, hdf5

I am doing an experiment with Dask which is a bit complicated so I cannot really provide a code snippet. This experiment uses dask threaded scheduler with only one thread (`'single-thread'`) to load an array of size about 5GB from a single `hdf5` file and to write it back into 50 `npy` files using dask array's `to_npy_stack` method. I am doing it in two parts, one buffer loading 2.5GB and the second one loading 2.5GB as well. The reading and writing are done on a HDD, hence my choice to use one thread. As we can see on the image below, dask diagnostics indicates me that the writing time in yellow (one task per writing in one numpy file) is a lot much longer than the reading part (the 2 blue tasks).

[image]

Does someone have an idea of why the reading time is that much faster than the writing time? As we can see from the bottom graph, I am loading 2.5GB on the cache so the decompression of the hdf5 file seems not to be delayed. Is it possible that the `to_numpy_stack` function is not well optimized?

PS: Yes, my dask diagnostics fails in the middle graph, I don't know why it depends on where I put it on my code. But anyway...

Edit: it seems that it is the usual writing time for numpy files so maybe it is just that the reading speed is greatly improved by the use of hdf5 even though it has to be uncompressed?

Answer (score 0):

You may be using slow compression on your numpy files (like gzip).  I recommend profiling your code so that you understand what is causing the slowdown.

Because you use the single threaded scheduler any traditional Python profiling tool, like cProfile, should work fine.